# How to set max height on react select

Tags: react-bootstrap

I'm trying to limit the height of a select list using the maxMenuHeight as follows:

```
  <Form.Control as="select" size="sm" className="w-auto" maxMenuHeight={20} defaultValue={currentTimezone.timezone}>
    {currentTimezoneList}
  </Form.Control>
```

However, the select list continues to be full height:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this using the "htmlSize" property of Form.Control which is documented here:

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#form-control-props